# In what state is a person affected by Hypnotic Pattern? Can they make saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

I'm reading the Hypnotic Pattern description and it says "Charmed, Incapacitated, Speed (0)" and "Snaps out of it, if being shaken or takes damage."

Then I read the various states you can be under:

- Charmed: can't attack the caster
- Incapacitated: can't take actions or reactions - is a save an action/reaction?
- Immobilized (Speed 0): Somewhere between Paralyzed, Restrained and Stunned — which all say you auto fail Strength and Dexterity saves and people have advantage on attacking you.

If I were to Fireball an individual (or group) under the influence of Hypnotic Pattern, would they get a Dexterity save to duck out of harm's way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***Hypnotic Pattern* has no impact on a saving throw whatsoever.** It imposes both the *Charmed* and *Incapacitated* conditions and having a speed of 0 does not automatically impose the *immobilized, paralyzed, restrained, or stunned* conditions, it just means you have a speed of 0. In fact, *immobilized* isn't even a condition in 5e.

Rules for saving throws can be found on page 179 of the *Player's Handbook* and nowhere does it say that they use either an action or a reaction, it simply says they "represent an attempt to resist a spell, a trap, a poison, a disease, or a similar threat" so being *Incapacitated* has no effect on this.

Being *charmed* means you can't attack or target the charmer with harmful effects but in no way affects your ability to "resist a spell, a trap, a poison, a disease, or a similar threat".

Conditions and spells that **do** affect savings throws explicitly note this fact in their descriptions.

Answer (score 3):

A save is neither an action nor a reaction - if it were, you would need to *use* your action or reaction in order to make a save. Effects that influence saves should always be clearly noted, because the save mechanic is an important part of the game.

Speed 0 is *not* the same as applying the Immobilized condition - except for sharing the effect on speed of course.

Creatures under the influence of Hypnotic Pattern may take Dexterity saves as normal (no penalty or disadvantage).